# PhoneGap 2.3.0 Plugin mapping

Tags: cordova

I have a qq, when I try to add a plugin to Cordova, I all the time had 1 small annoying issue and I am not sure how can I fix it.

so: PDFViewer plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PDFViewer

I follow all instructions, as well updating the config.xml file,

EX: `<plugin name="PDFViewerCommand" value="PDFViewerCommand" />`

but the issues is when I try to split plugin by folder in "Plugins" folder.

I mean if I extract all  "name.h, name.m" in the root of the plugin folder , it works fine.

But because I can have more then 1 plugin, it will a bi a big mess. SO I want to split plugins by folders:

EX:

- Plugins -- > PdfViewEr
- Plugins -- > ChildBrowser
- Plugins -- > New Plugin

I know it should be something related with mapping or somewhere I can declare the folder name.